# Clarification needed on asking etiquette

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, rules

Hello I am new to SO and I want to make as good an impression as possible.  I asked a question and received a satisfactory response in the context for which it was asked.  I have since discovered new issues related to the original that render the original answer incorrect for my purposes or at least incomplete.  Due to a new broader scope to my problem, I need to take the issue in a different direction.  How should I approach this?

A. Add the new problems as clarification comments in the original question.
B. Edit the original question.
C. Create a new question linking to the original.
D. There is a completely different solution that I haven't considered.

I appreciate you taking the time to read my query.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for asking for clarification.

C is the best option most of the time, especially if the new problems with the code are a different issue.

B is appropriate only when you forgot details of the original problem.

A, or using comments for adding details or changes is never appropriate, as that's what edits are for.